# Archive of old eBay auctions

Tags: ebay

Where can I find a complete or nearly complete archive of past eBay auctions?

eBay only lets me search auctions up to 60 days ago but I want to search everything for the last few years.

Answer (score 9):

eBay deletes auctions to save on computing resources.

Managing a database of sold items is not eBay's objective, nor is it in their business model. Once an auction is done with feedback given or return process completed, there is no reason for eBay to store these auctions.

There is no-way to get back auctions that are deleted from the ~60 day archive. The only auctions that are archived for longer are auctions with some kind of significance; e.g. an item of high value or otherwise remarkable.

Also from what I've experienced it is more likely to see a very old sold auction when the seller is either a professional or there were multiple items in the auction. Other than that there is no getting back to auctions older than 60 days.

Being 2019, I think some things done at eBay have actually changed, and while eBay still doesn't at least publicly display closed and archived auctions any more than previously; I have noticed a change on purchases, where I think the auction images are being saved for longer. Perhaps this is related to some internal changes in order to better have data for Big data and ML/AI related endeavors.

Comment: I don't doubt that eBay removes old auctions, but to do it to "save space"? That is dubious, especially when storage is dirt-cheap. Now, if they were doing it to keep from having to index auctions in their search engine database, that I'd believe.

Comment: You are on the right track. This is why I said "computing space". Storage is not the issue; large databases, cpu cycles, power usage and bandwidth are. Storing all the auctions for past 10 years would make for _massive_ databases, which would incur serious problems if not managed properly. Managing such databases is not eBay's objective, nor is it in their business model. Once an auction is done with feedback given or return process completed, there is no reason for eBay to store these auctions.

Answer (score 2):

Worthpoint.com stores keywords for unique or valuable items for about 10 years but you cannot search by eBay item number.

Answer (score 0):

`https://picclick.co.uk/-N.html` where `N` is the item ID seems to work, but not for all items. Note that the `-` is necessary.